# reformat short per-line data into a(n indexed) tabular layout to fill my terminal

Tags: bash, command-line, text-formatting

I have a text file containing a small piece of data on each line: Maybe it's a word, or a single number. For simplicity let's assume there are no empty lines and no headers within that file. For example, suppose my input is:

```
hobby
anger
experienced
profession
golf
director
code
telephone
```

Now, I want to have that input laid out on my terminal in a tabular form, row-major, preserving order. Suppose my terminal is 40 chars wide; this could be:

```
hobby      anger     experienced
profession golf      director
code       telephone
```

(but I'm also ok with the columns all having the same width.)

A concise way of doing that without a long shell script would already be nice. Beyond this, I would also like to have indices, like so:

```
   0          1         2
0  hobby      anger     experienced
3  profession golf      director
6  code       telephone
```

This is doable with `nl --line-increment`, but the thing is, I would need to know the number of columns before I know what the maximum index is, and I need the maximum index to know what the index column width is, and I need to know the index column width to decide how many columns can fit in a row, so we have a bit of a viciuous cycle.

---

What I have so far:

If I forego any aligment, as well as auto-maximization of number of columns per line, I can use:

```
per_line=3;  pr -a -${per_line} -t -s\  | nl -v 0 --line-increment ${per_line}
```

to get:

```
     0  hobby anger experienced
     3  profession golf director
     6  code telephone
```

Comment: If you were OK with all columns being the same width rather than each column being 1 longer than the max length of the words in that column then it'd become a much simpler problem to solve. Otherwise I think you're stuck iterating on each number of columns starting at 1 until you hit the max that'll fit inside 40 chars and then print with that. Either way, I'd use an awk script for this, don't try to piece it together from other Unix tools called from shell loops.

Comment: @EdMorton: I am actually ok with that. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Your question isn't clear on what you consider acceptable output and so multiple people are guessing at what that might be. Is anything with 3 words per line and numbered lines acceptable as shown in the output of the command pipeline at the end of your question? If so that's a vastly simpler problem than the one you described above it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine. The file `input` contains the code content you posted.

First I generate numbers 0 1 2 and the file content with 3 columns separted by `,`.

Then for lines starting from the second line, lines are numbered.

AFter that, nice column is created.

```
$ ( seq 3; cat input; ) | paste -d, - - - | ( read;echo ",$REPLY"; nl -v 0 -i 3 -s, ) | column -t -s,
        1           2          3
     0  hobby       anger      experienced
     3  profession  golf       director
     6  code        telephone
```

Right `pr` exists, I usually use `paste` for columns:

```
(seq 3; cat input) | pr -a -3 -t -s, - | (read; echo ",$REPLY"; nl -v 0 -i 3 -s,) | column -t -s,
```

So:

```
indextable() {
   (seq "$1"; shift; cat "$@") |
       pr -a -"$1" -t -s, - |
       (read; echo ",$REPLY"; nl -v 0 -i "$1" -s,) |
       column -t -s,
}
indextable 3 input
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of `$REPLY` in that script?

Comment: `read; echo ",$REPLY"` - read one line and output it (with a leading `,`). The default variable for `read` is `REPLY`. In bash.

Comment: Your first-line `seq` should start at 0 though.

Answer (score 1):

A concise way to get pretty close to your desired result is `column -c 50 -x input.txt | nl`, which gives:

```
     1  hobby           anger           experienced
     2  profession      golf            director
     3  code            telephone
```

Long options format: `column --output-width 50 --fillrows input.txt | nl`

Comment: Ah, but you're "cheating" slightly: The value for output-width should be such, that applying the `nl`, the line is as filled as it can be.

Comment: @einpoklum why is THAT cheating when specifying a number of columns and not specifying a max line width (both of which you do in  [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78108387/1745001)) isn't cheating? That's what I mean when I say your requirements aren't clear - please edit your question to state your requirements for an acceptable answer.

Comment: @EdMorton: 1. my answer also cheats somewhat. 2. I +1'ed this answer.

Comment: I think you're missing my point - in your mind you have an idea of what an acceptable answer might be but you haven't told us what that is and so the question and answers are practically useless as a future reference for others with a similar question (the main purpose for this site) because you haven't stated in the question what the question actually is.

Comment: All we know for sure so far is you want output with columns - the column headers may or may not be present in the output, you may or may not need to specify a width, you may or may not be able to specify a number of columns, column widths could be constant or varying per column or varying per word, etc... This could be the most trivial of problems to solve or the most complex depending on what the problem actually is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to forego automatic figuring-out of the optimal number of columns, you can set a `${num_cols}` , then use this:

```
pr -a -${num_cols} -t -s, -  | \
nl -v 0 --line-increment ${num_cols} | \
column -s, -t
```

and on your input, this gives:

```
     0  hobby       anger      experienced
     3  profession  golf       director
     6  code        telephone
```

which is more or less what you wanted.

Comment: Regarding "more or less what **you** wanted" (emphasis mine) - ITYM "more or less what **I** wanted" since you asked the question. There are lots of possibilities for doing things that are "more or less" what you wanted, how should we know which are acceptable and which aren't? How will you decide which answer to accept when you get multiple that do "more or less" what you asked for, as is currently happening?

Comment: @EdMorton: 1. I wrote this answer as a WIP, to hopefully perfect later on. Plus, I was a little fuzzy about what to do regarding the indexing. 2. The OP (in this case me) needs to know what's acceptable. 3. I used the second person because I'm answering a question. Yes, the question happens to have been asked by me, but that is not very consequential. I always write self-answers in the second person and I think that's the right way to go about it.

Comment: It's not enough for the OP to know what's acceptable, the OP has to state in their question what's acceptable. Otherwise you can ask "what color is the sky?" and if you get the answer "kittens" maybe that's acceptable to you and so the question is useless as a reference for others with a similar question in future.